# where does a redirection comes from on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am redirecting the user after a model save.

```
if @client.save
  redirect_to :new_course
```

on the new course controller I have no redirection

```
def new
  @course = Course.new
end
```

After the course_controller#new is been executed I am been redirected on another controller view.

I can't figure out where does this redirection comes from.

I am tracing the application and seen that

```
Started GET "/courses/new" for ::1 at 2015-10-01 15:01:46 -0400
Processing by CoursesController#new as */*
Therapist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "therapists".* FROM "therapists"  WHERE "therapists"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "therapists"."id" ASC LIMIT 1   [["id", 14]]
Rendered courses/new.html.erb within layouts/application (228.3ms)
Client Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "clients" WHERE  "clients"."therapist_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["therapist_id", 14]]
Completed 200 OK in 679ms (Views: 652.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)


Started GET "/clients/show" for ::1 at 2015-10-01 15:01:46 -0400
Processing by ClientsController#show as HTML
Therapist Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "therapists".* FROM "therapists" WHERE "therapists"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "therapists"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 14]]
Rendered clients/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Client Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."therapist_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["therapist_id", 14]]
Client Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."therapist_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["therapist_id", 14]]
Client Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."therapist_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["therapist_id", 14]]
Completed 200 OK in 371ms (Views: 367.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `redirect_to` method sends a response to the browser that indicates it should load a new page. Then Rails is finished and waits for another request, that controller object is destroyed as it's no longer needed.

This is typically done with the `Location:` header in the HTTP response.

The next request to come in is the result of this redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Rails sets up some default redirects based on common functionality.  Basically, after you create a new object it assumes you will want to go view it and redirects to the #show action.  If you want it to go somewhere else you need to set up that route.

As I recall there are also instances where rails will default an action you haven't created for instance, if you have an index action in your routes but never set it up rails will make one for you with @my_items = MyItems.all and render the index view.